# Error while installing bootstrap dependencies

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, npm

> D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap>npm install /
>
> > phantomjs@1.9.17 install D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap\node_
> >     modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phanto
> >     mjs
> >     node install.js
>
> Downloading
>   https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-wind
>   ows.zip Saving to
>   C:\Users\HackCorp\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows
>   .zip Receiving... / [=====================================---] 93%
>   0.0s| Received 7292K total. Extracting zip contents Removing D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap\node_modules\grunt-cont
>   rib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom
>   Copying extracted folder
>   C:\Users\HackCorp\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomj
>   s-1.9.8-windows.zip-extract-1432441255719\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows ->
>   D:\MyStuff\
>   Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modul
>   es\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modules\phantomjs\lib\phantom Writing
>   location.js file Done. Phantomjs binary available at
>   D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootst
>   rap\node_modules\grunt-contrib-qunit\node_modules\grunt-lib-phantomjs\node_modul
>   es\phantomjs\lib\phantom\phantomjs.exe npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs \node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR!
>   node v0.12.2 npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4 npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR!
>   errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! syscall connect
>
> npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network This is most
>   likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and is related
>   to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind
>   a proxy or have bad network settin gs. npm ERR! network npm ERR!
>   network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR!
>   network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!
>   D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap\npm-debug.log
>
> D:\MyStuff\Documents\workspace\behalv\bootstrap>

**There is no proxy configuration setup in my PC.
Kindly help.**